# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas datastructure, which I create like this:

```
test_inputs = pd.read_csv("../input/test.csv", delimiter=',')
```

Its shape

```
print(test_inputs.shape)
```

is this

```
(28000, 784)
```

I would like to print a subset of its rows, like this:

```
print(test_inputs[100:200, :])
print(test_inputs[100:200, :].shape)
```

However, I am getting:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `test_inputs[100:200]` or `test_inputs.loc[100:200, :]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is more possible solutions, but output is not same:

`loc` selects by labels, but `iloc` and slicing without function, the start bounds is **included**, while the upper bound is **excluded**, [docs - select by positions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position):

```
test_inputs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(28, 7)))

print(test_inputs.loc[10:20])
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
10  3  2  0  6  6  0  0
11  5  0  2  4  1  5  2
12  5  3  5  4  1  3  5
13  9  5  6  6  5  0  1
14  7  0  7  4  2  2  5
15  2  4  3  3  7  2  3
16  8  9  6  0  5  3  4
17  1  1  0  7  2  7  7
18  1  2  2  3  5  8  7
19  5  1  1  0  1  8  9
20  3  6  7  3  9  7  1
```

---

```
print(test_inputs.iloc[10:20])
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
10  3  2  0  6  6  0  0
11  5  0  2  4  1  5  2
12  5  3  5  4  1  3  5
13  9  5  6  6  5  0  1
14  7  0  7  4  2  2  5
15  2  4  3  3  7  2  3
16  8  9  6  0  5  3  4
17  1  1  0  7  2  7  7
18  1  2  2  3  5  8  7
19  5  1  1  0  1  8  9

print(test_inputs[10:20])
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
10  3  2  0  6  6  0  0
11  5  0  2  4  1  5  2
12  5  3  5  4  1  3  5
13  9  5  6  6  5  0  1
14  7  0  7  4  2  2  5
15  2  4  3  3  7  2  3
16  8  9  6  0  5  3  4
17  1  1  0  7  2  7  7
18  1  2  2  3  5  8  7
19  5  1  1  0  1  8  9
```

Answer (score 10):

Indexing in pandas is really confusing, as it looks like list indexing but it is not. You need to use `.iloc`, which is indexing by position

```
print(test_inputs.iloc[100:200, :])
```

And if you don't use column selection you can omit it

```
print(test_inputs.iloc[100:200])
```

P.S. Using `.loc` is not what you want, as it would look not for the row number, but for the row index (which can be filled we anything, not even numbers, not even unique). Ranges in `.loc` will find rows with index value 100 and 200, and return the lines between. If you just created the DataFrame `.iloc` and `.loc` may give the same result, but using `.loc` in this case is a very bad practice as it will lead you to difficult to understand problem when the index will change for some reason (for example you'll select some subset of rows, and from that moment the row number and index will not be the same).

P.P.S. You can use `test_inputs[100:200]`, but not `test_inputs[100:200, :`] because pandas designers tried to combine different popular approaches into one construction. And `test_input['column']` equals to `test_input.loc[:, 'column']`, but surprisingly slicing with integers `test_input[100:200]` equals to `test_inputs.iloc[100:200]` (while slicing with not integer values is equivalent to `loc` row slicing). And if you pass a pair of values to [] it considers as a tuple for multilevel column indexing so `multi_level_columns_df['level_1', 'level_2']` is equivalent to `multi_level_columns_df.loc[:, ('level_1', 'level_2')]`. That is why your original construction led to the error: slice can't be used as a part of multilevel index.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Even the above solutions couldn't fix it. It was some problem with pandas, What I did was I changed the array into a numpy array that fixed the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test_inputs = pd.read_csv("../input/test.csv", delimiter=',')
test_inputs = np.asarray(test_inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(test_inputs.values[100:200, :])
print(test_inputs.values[100:200, :].shape)
```

This code is also working for me.