# Pandas and NumPy won't read entire file

Tags: python, pandas

I was using panda.read_table for gathering a tabular file into a matrix. However, panada process the first 4772 rows of line without any problem, and then it jumps the error as following:

```
return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\YOUJIA LI\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\YOUJIA LI\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2487, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Here is the code I am using for processing the data:

```
 from get_line_number import get_line_number
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#import file in python
phrase = "STARTS"
file_name = "C:\\Users\\YOUJIA LI\\Desktop\\program\\java\\LAYER.PLT" #（change path ）

#find where the file starts
linenumber = get_line_number(phrase,file_name)
with open(file_name) as myfile:
    lineskip = myfile.readlines()[int(linenumber):]

#create a temp. file to store the numerical data
file = open("token.txt",'w')
with open(file_name) as myfile:
    for _ in range(linenumber):
        next(myfile)
    for line in myfile:
        values = line.split()
        # get ride of string leave num along
        values1 = str(values).replace("[","")
        values1 = values1.replace("]","")
        values1 = values1.replace("'","")

        file.write(values1 +'\n')
myfile.close()
matrix = pd.read_table('token.txt', sep=',',header=None,error_bad_lines=False)
print(matrix)
```

The screen shot of the token.txt as following: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P1rv.png)

Comment: Can you post the whole error.  It may be helpful to see where the error originates in your code.

Comment: Why do you have nested lists in your CSV?

Comment: i think this might answer your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871017/typeerror-unhashable-type-slice-for-panda